# Regular expression to extract text after Username

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Looking for `preg_match_all` to extract any username found in a text. Example text is 'last_name, first_name Username:bjorge, Username philip kardashian, kim username: mercury, freddie'

What I'm trying to capture in this text:

-bjorge

-philip

-mercury

I tried this but no go:
`preg_match_all("/(Username:|Username)\s+?(\S+)/i", $input_lines, $output_array);`

This is the output I get from what I tried.

`array(30=>last_name, first_name 1=>last_name 2=>first_name)
array(30=>bjorge, philip 1=>bjorge 2=>philip)
array(30=>kardashian, kim 1=>kardashian 2=>kim)
array(30=>mercury, freddie 1=>mercury 2=>freddie)`

Comment: What exactly does not work? Why? What about the whitespace there? Is it obligatory? Try `"/Username:?\s*(\S+)/i"`, or `"/Username:?\s*(\w+)/i"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string `'last_name, first_name Username:bjorge, Username philip kardashian, kim username: mercury, freddie'`, there're no spaces before `bjorge`.

Use:

```
preg_match_all("/(Username:|Username)\s*(\S+)/i", $input_lines, $output_array);
//                              here __^
```

I've simplified your regex:

```
$in = 'last_name, first_name Username:bjorge, Username philip kardashian, kim username: mercury, freddie';
preg_match_all("/Username:?\s*(\S+)/i", $in, $out);
print_r($out);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Username:bjorge,
            [1] => Username philip
            [2] => username: mercury,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bjorge,
            [1] => philip
            [2] => mercury,
        )

)
```